# Should "openssl" be a synonym of "https"?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There are questions in [`openssl`](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openssl) and [`https`](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/https). Should "openssl" be added as a synonym, like [`ssl`](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssl) already is? All of the existing questions appear to be about HTTPS & SSL certificates, and not actually about the OpenSSL application.

Answer (score 4):

If the questions aren't actually about OpenSSL, it would be better to remove the tag from those questions.

Because OpenSSL is a product, I don't think it makes sense to make it a synonym of HTTPS the way that we have done for SSL.